# Google Chrome extenstion - local storage set and get

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, google-chrome

I'm developing an extension for Google Chrome, and have run into some trouble.I created an options.html page and added it to the manifest.json file.The page shows properly.

Further I need to save the filled data in local storage there I am not able to proceed ahead

Can you help me to get the code to execute local storage by set and get

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uyuva.jpg)[entryt form[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fiy2.jpg)

Manifest

```
{
   "background": {
      "scripts": [ "background.js" ]
   },
   "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "t19.png"
   },
   "description": "Fill out web forms instantly with junk or custom data",
   "icons": {
      "128": "t128.png",
      "48": "t48.png"
   },

   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "Tatkal on budget style",
   "options_page": "entry_form.html",
   "permissions": [ "storage",  "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
   "version": "1.0"
}`enter code here`


Background

chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.create({'url': chrome.extension.getURL('entry_form.html')}, function(tab) {
    // Tab opened.
  });
});
```

Looking forward to have the code for local storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome extension doesnt support localstorage. You will have to use `chrome.storage.sync` (syncs data for the user across devices) or `chrome.storage.local` (local to the current chrome instance).
lets say u want to save a field called name with value as John.
Localstorage:

```
localstorage.setItem('name', 'Jogn');
```

Chrome extension

```
var obj = {
    name:'Jogn'
}
chrome.storage.sync.set(obj, function () {
    //success callback
});
```

to get the stored name use:

```
var keys = ['name'];
chrome.storage.sync.get(key, function (result) {
    // the received result  field will be an object
    console.log(result.name);
});
```

Comment: Hi Bij thanks for your kind reply i tried to implement your code on background.js but it did not worked for me, can you please briefly explain me, thanks in advance for your kind support

Comment: In order to use this you need to request `storage` permission. Have you added `storage` under `permissions` in you `manifest` file

Comment: Yes added in manifest, i posted code of manifest also in my question